# How to view the last updated tables in a db2 server?

Tags: sql, database, db2

When we write a query or any query that updates some of tables in the DB can we able to see in which are the tables that query has inserted a new records into.

I need to view the tables which are recently updated after the query runs?

Comment: Which Db2 version/platform?

Answer (score 0):

The [Activity event monitoring](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.mon.doc/doc/c0055565.html) topic describes the use of some sort of a "logger" for queries with their performance characteristics. If such a "logging" is turned on for your session, you can find the corresponding information in tables of this event monitor in your database.

There is no list of tables affected by queries (query text only) in these tables, but you can get them to your explain tables, if you process the queries captured by this event monitor with the [EXPLAIN_FROM_ACTIVITY](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0056203.html) routine.